# Regular Expressions, character count limitation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to write a tiny number validator, I want it to validate if the input is a number and that works. I also want to validate that the input is a number between the length of say 10 and 20, no shorter no longer. I first thought it would be as simple as `/^[0-9]{10-20}$/` but apparently not. So after googling and reading around, I seem to find that, well, I can't find the answer.

How to limit the input to a certain amount of characters with use of Regexp? Any articles on the subject is welcome as well as ideas on how to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct [syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is `{10,20}` (with a comma).